# ORA-31011: XML parsing failed on function condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

On a client's database (which I do not have physical access to) we are getting some strange results when joining to a function.

I was able to guide them to replicate the issue on a completely new schema within the same database.

```
create or replace function GEN_FILENAME(p_file_name varchar2) return varchar2
is
    l_filename varchar2(100);
begin
    l_filename := 'Test' || '/' || 'Test' || '.' || initcap(p_file_name) || '.txt';   
    return l_filename;
end GEN_FILENAME;
/
```

The function generates the following error if I use equals on a join, but is fine when I use a sub select for the function.

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19213: error occurred in XML processing at lines 1
LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
```

```
-- this query does not work
select              dt.file_name,
                    GEN_FILENAME(dt.file_name) as file_name,
                    mf.file_path
from                (   select      'Test'                          FOLDER, 
                                    'Test'                          AREA,
                                    'File_Name'                     FILE_NAME,
                                    systimestamp                    LAST_MODIFIED
                        from dual
                    ) dt
left outer join     (select 'Test/Test.File_Name.txt' file_path from dual) mf on mf.file_path = GEN_FILENAME(dt.file_name);

-- this query is working
select              dt.file_name,
                    GEN_FILENAME(dt.file_name) as file_name,
                    mf.file_path
from                (   select      'Test'                          FOLDER, 
                                    'Test'                          AREA,
                                    'File_Name'                     FILE_NAME,
                                    systimestamp                    LAST_MODIFIED
                        from dual
                    ) dt
left outer join     (select 'Test/Test.File_Name.txt' file_path from dual) mf on mf.file_path = (select GEN_FILENAME(dt.file_name) from dual);
```

I have seen other odd issues as well. I have asked them to gather statistics of the tables in the schema.

```
begin
  for i in (select TABLE_NAME from USER_TABLES) loop
    --Gather Table Statistics
    sys.dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( ownname => 'TEST', tabname => i.TABLE_NAME, cascade => true);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
ORA-20000: Unable to analyze TABLE "TEST"."LOGMNR_SESSION_EVOLVE$", insufficient privileges or does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40751
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40024
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40183
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 40732
ORA-06512: at line 5
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I think this is all related, but I have never seen this type of issues before.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Seems to work in 18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=549b6fe6855219e920954178d9d26c9f); though your example doesn't have any XML so it's unclear whether (or how) you see the exact error you showed. Which database version and patch level are you seeing a problem in? And do you have two functions called `GEN_FILENAME`, maybe with different specifications; or the failing call is in a package that has its own version that's taking precedence?

Comment: I am using 19c and there are no duplicate functions. The XML is the weird part, I've tested the same code on multiple of other installations. 
I am convinced that the issues lies with their database.